# Persistent variable in Python function

Tags: python, class

I've got this script written which does some involved parsing while running through a large file. For every line in the file (after some heavy manipulation), I need to add a check to see whether it meets certain criteria and if it does, include it in a list for additional processing later.

The function doing the parsing is already a bit cluttered, and I'm wondering whether it's possible to shunt the line-checking and list manipulation to another function to make things easier to modify later on. My inclination is to use a global variable which gets modified by the function, but I know that's usually poor form. Until now I have never made use of classes, but I vaguely recall there being some advantage to them regarding persistent local variables.

One version of this part of the script could be:

```
matchingLines = []
def lineProcess(line):
    global matchingLines
    if line.startswith(criteria):
        matchingLines.append(line)
for line in myFile:
    # lots of other stuff
    lineProcess(line)
```

Obviously in this simple example it's not much of a pain to just do the checking in the main function and not bother with any additional functions. But in principle, I'm wondering what a better general way of doing this sort of thing is without using external variables.

EDIT: Part of the reason I find the separate function attractive is because once I've collected the list of lines, I am going to use them to manipulate another external file and it would be convenient to have the whole operate wrapped up in a contained module. However, I recognize that this might be premature optimization.

Comment: Actually the particular problem is answered but not the question wich is how to make a variable persistent into a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following might be considered more pythonic:

```
def is_valid_line(line):
    """Return True if the line is valid, else False."""
    return line.startswith(criteria)

valid_lines = [l for l in myFile if is_valid_line(l)]
```

Incidentally it would be even better practice to use a generator expression rather than a list e.g.

```
valid_lines = (l for l in myFile if is_valid_line(l))
```

That way the file reading and line-validation will only actually happen when something tries to iterate over valid_lines, and not before. E.g. In the following case:

```
valid_lines = [l for l in myFile if is_valid_line(l)]
for line in valid lines:
    stuff_that_can_raise_exception(line)
```

In this case, you have read and validated the entire (huge) file and have the full list of validated lines, and then the first line causes an error, the time spent validating the whole file is wasted. If you use a generator expression (the `(x for x in y)`) version instead of a list comprehension (the `[x for x in y]`) then when the error happens you haven't actually validated the file yet (only the first line). I only mention it because I am terrible for not doing this more often myself, and it can yield big performance gains (in CPU and memory) in a lot of cases.

Comment: Definitely. As I wrote in response to Eevee, perhaps I'm asking too philosophical a question. I'd like to have a system which scales well with complexity, and depending on the criteria involved I suspect this sort of solution will only take me so far.

Comment: You could create a separate module with your own class that subclasses File, and have that class effectively 'hide' all the non matching lines. But I'm not sure that has anything to do with global variables - I'm still not really clear why you think you might need one at all? If you can give an example of how the system might need to be made more complex, we can offer some tips for what architecture or design patterns might help.

Comment: Yeah, I may be suffering from a case of not-planning-the-question-out-before-asking-it syndrome. The global variables come into play because all of the above is happening itself within a function, and the file processing I need to do with the matching list would happen outside of the parent function here. Of course, I could make this parent function return the matching list, but that would involve rewriting a lot of other stuff. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yep. It does sound like getting the validator to return an iterable of valid lines would be the way to go... Sorry it might be painful!

Comment: +1 I appreciate the generator info. I use the heck out of list comprehensions, but this is for a bioinformatics application where the text files can be many GB so anything that avoids necessarily running through the file is worth investigating.

Comment: Even if it doesn't avoid running through the entire dataset/iterable, it can mean that you don't need to store it all in memory *at the same time*, which is often a good saving. Glad it's useful :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69974/discussion-between-glarue-and-tom-dalton).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a class, and have `matching_lines` be an attribute.  But you could also just do this:

```
def process_line(line, matching_lines):
    if line.startswith(criteria):
        matching_lines.append(line)

...

matches = []
for line in my_file:
    # lots of other stuff
    process_line(line, matches)
```

Comment: Right, thanks for the response. I probably should have put together a more formal example, but I guess what I'm asking it what is the best way to do this sort of thing in general, to accommodate increasingly complex parsing tasks (i.e. not just a simple startswith() check or whatever) without overusing globals